# cmd does not recognize any commands

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm on Windows 10, the `cmd` does not recognize `any commands`.
It return always:

> "the name of the commande" is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program, or a batch file

after Google search, I found that I should modifiy the Path in `Environment Variables` to add this line bellow, but it does not resolve the problem:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

[image]

Someone please can tell me how can I resolve this problem?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a few of the commands which exhibit this behaviour, exactly as you typed them. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46520981/edit), to add this information for us.

Comment: All commands, even ls

Comment: `ls` is not a Windows command as Windows is not POSIX compliant.

Comment: Try `xcopy`. Or format your hard drive and install *NIX.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Why `xcopy`? Wouldn't `dir` do the job?

Comment: @SteveFest `dir` is built in in cmd. `xcopy` shouldn't be

Comment: You appear to have modified the default value of **`Path`** under **`Variables utilisateur pour user`**, _(which should point to **`%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;`** including the trailing semi-colon)_, adding a value which shoudn't be necessary. You have more likely misconfigured your **`Variables systéme`**, the entries in the lower pane. You should first attempt to **repair/restore** your system to the most recent time before your broke it. If that fails you could edit **`Path`** under **`Variables systéme`** to match the value data retrieved from your Google search.

Comment: @Compo The `%comSpec%` variable is also misconfigured. It should be `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe` but now it's `%windir%\system32%` That could be another error that could "disable" program from calling `cmd` via `%comSpec%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` is **NOT** a standard Windows command! `DIR` is the Windows equivalent to `ls`.

---

To see a list of Windows supported command, enter `help`. The example output:

```
>help
For more information on a specific command, type HELP command-name.
ASSOC          Displays or modifies file extension associations.
...
```

Comment: `LS` is not a command in general. `ls` however is.